# how I can insert data from database into below array?

Tags: php, arrays

how can I insert data from the database into the below array? I've tried several ways but I still fail.

I want to insert value data from the database into an array

```
class topsis {
public $alternatif = array();
public $kriteria = array();

public function __construct()
{

    // data kriteria
    array_push($this->kriteria, array('Nilai Akademik', 5, 'Benefit'));
    array_push($this->kriteria, array('Historis Project', 4, 'Benefit'));
    array_push($this->kriteria, array('Pelatihan', 3, 'Benefit'));
    array_push($this->kriteria, array('Minat', 4, 'Benefit'));
    // data alternatif
    array_push($this->alternatif, array('Sistem Pakar', 5, 1, 2, 5));
    array_push($this->alternatif, array('Data Mining', 5, 1, 3, 5));
    array_push($this->alternatif, array('SPK', 5, 1, 3, 4));
    array_push($this->alternatif, array('Citra', 4, 1, 3, 3));
    array_push($this->alternatif, array('Jaringan Komputer', 5, 4, 3, 4));
}

public function pembagi()
{
    $this->pembagi = array(0, 0, 0, 0);
    foreach ($this->alternatif as $a) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->kriteria); $i++) {
            $this->pembagi[$i] += pow($a[$i + 1], 2);
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->pembagi); $i++) {
        $this->pembagi[$i] = round(sqrt($this->pembagi[$i]), 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: You run a query on the database, fetch the data, and then push it into the array. Without more details of the data you want to fetch, what DB library you're using, or what code you've already tried and what specific problem you had, we can't give you any more detailed help than that. See also [ask]. I suggested you [edit] the question when you're ready, to give it more clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to create a connection with the database. You can do this by choosing a procedural way, using libraries and modules specific to your database, or an object-like way, in which you use a standard interface to interact with it, the PDO (Php Data Object). Now, you can choose one option based on the db you use and how you'd like to interact with it.